# Spring MVC Not getting back any results with ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc

I want to get data about my user from ajax request. But it never logs anything, which means it never reaches to success part of ajax request.

This is my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/profile")
public class ProfilController {

@Autowired
public UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/show/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> showData(@PathVariable String username) {
    User u = userService.findByUsername(username);
    if(!userService.findAll().contains(u))
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new UserDTO(u), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

And this is my java script file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log(localStorage.getItem('loggedIn'));
var usrnm = localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');

$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/api/user/login/check/"+usrnm,
  type: "GET",
  headers: {"Authorization": localStorage.jwt},
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('success');
  }
})

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/show/"+usrnm,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('This part is not executed');
    }
  })
});
```

I am new to Spring, actually I am new to programming so sorry if this question is not well formatted

Comment: request & response are nothing? show me network status.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you asked for.. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S017HFGTgjlCRkD-lPZa_-R5F_uANHyw)

Comment: you have to check request network status. such as 200 ok; 404 not found; 500 server error;

Comment: You can see in the picture that i get 404 status, but not sure why

Answer (score 0):

You may have an error in the showData function. You should do the following:
    `@PathVariable("username") String username`

Comment: Still nothing. [This is](https://imgur.com/a/OVJsLn0) console output if it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/profile") // fixed this!!! remove `value = `
public class ProfilController {
    @Autowired
    public UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/show/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> showData(@PathVariable String username) {
        User u = userService.findByUsername(username);
        if(!userService.findAll().contains(u))
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new UserDTO(u), HttpStatus.OK);
      }
    }
```